# Getting error of undefined when fetching data from sanity.io in next.js

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, sanity

I'm pretty new to the headless cms of sanity.io. As I'm trying to fetch my data im getting this error but couldn't figure out why or where the problem could be exactly.

Anybody some ideas?

Error: Error serializing `.images` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/company/[slug]".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.

//the slug file

```
export const Company = ({ title, slug, logo, images, currency, categories, body, url, location }) => {
    console.log(title, slug, logo, images, currency, categories, body, url, location )
    return <>Content</>
};

export const getServerSideProps = async pageContext => {
    const pageSlug = pageContext.query.slug;

    if (!pageSlug) {
        return {
            notFound: true
        }
    }

    const query = encodeURIComponent(`*[ _type == "company" && slug.current == "${pageSlug}" ]`);
    const url = `https://op5ktqwm.api.sanity.io/v1/data/query/production?query=${query}`;

    const result = await fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
    const post = result.result[0];

    if (!post) {
        return {
            notFound: true
        }
    } else {
        return {
            props: {
                title: post.title,
                slug: post.slug,
                logo: post.logo,
                images: post.images,
                currency: post.currency,
                categories: post.categories,
                body: post.body,
                url: post.url,
                location: post.location
            }
        }
    }
}

export default Company;
```

//backend code structure

```
export default {
  name: 'company',
  title: 'Company',
  type: 'document',
  fields: [
    {
      name: 'title',
      title: 'Title',
      type: 'string',
    },
    {
      name: 'slug',
      title: 'Slug',
      type: 'slug',
      options: {
        source: 'title',
        maxLength: 96,
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'logo',
      title: 'Logo',
      type: 'image',
    },
    {
      name: 'images',
      title: 'Images',
      type: 'array',
      of: [{type: 'companyImage'}]
    },
    {
      name: 'currency',
      title: 'Currency',
      type: 'array',
      of: [
        {
          type: 'reference',
          to: {type: 'currency'},
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'categories',
      title: 'Categories',
      type: 'array',
      of: [
        {
          type: 'reference',
          to: {type: 'category'},
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'body',
      title: 'Body',
      type: 'localeBlockContent',
    },
    {
      name: 'url',
      title: 'URL',
      type: 'string',
    },
    {
      name: 'location',
      title: 'Location',
      type: 'geopoint',
    },
    
  ],

  preview: {
    select: {
      title: 'title',
      manufactor: 'manufactor.title',
      media: 'defaultProductVariant.images[0]',
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: as I'm using google chrome yes

Comment: I figured out that when just deleting images it works fine. But of course this could not be the solution :)

Comment: can you do `console.log(post.images)` just to see the value of `images`?

Comment: not getting any values just error message in the console

Comment: did you check the console inside your code editor? the one where you ran `npm run dev`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.